# How to query an ampersand symbol in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table that has names and addresses.  Some of these name fields are both names of a couple -- for example, "John & Jane".

I am trying to write a query that pulls out only those rows where this is the case.

When I run this query, it selects 0 rows even though I know that they exist in the table:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM name_list where namefirst LIKE '%&%';
```

Does anyone know how to address this?

Comment: `LIKE '%&%'` should be returning any `namefirst` which has an ampersand in it.  [Check this demo](https://rextester.com/WHNQC23663) where your logic is clearly working.

Comment: Works for me!™ Are you running this query directly? Or as part of a larger program? If it's part of a larger program, please show us the code which is executing the query.